# What does Voldemort mean when he asks Wormtail to 'milk' Nagini?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

> “Where is Nagini?” said the cold voice.
>
> “I I don’t know, my Lord,” said the first voice nervously. “She set out to explore the house, I think. . . .”
>
> **“You will milk her before we retire,** Wormtail,” said the second voice. “I will need feeding in the night. The journey has tired me greatly.”

**How would one milk a giant magical snake? Would milk actually be produced, or is milk just a verb that would actually produce another magical substance?**

Comment: How do you milk a giant, magical, venomous snake? Verrry carefully.

Comment: I can't imagine the poison will have any health benefits if drunk, though . . . maybe Voldemort is just extra immune.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Snakes are "[milked](http://www.jobmonkey.com/uniquejobs/snake-milker.html)" by expressing the teeth against a rubberised (or flat) surface and then massaging the venom glands in order to collect the snake's venom. In the real world, this would then be used to produce anti-venom. In the wizarding world, Voldemort uses Nagini's venom to create his [rudimentary body potion](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Rudimentary_Body_Potion)

[image]

Later we learn the use to which the venom was put;

> Wormtail was able to follow the instructions I gave him, which would
>   return me to a rudimentary, weak body of my own, a body I would be
>   able to inhabit while awaiting the essential ingredients for true
>   rebirth … a spell or two of my own invention … **a little help from my
>   dear Nagini’ – Voldemort’s red eyes fell upon the continually circling
>   snake – ‘a potion concocted from unicorn blood, and the snake venom
>   Nagini provided** … I was soon returned to an almost human form, and
>   strong enough to travel. <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire</sup></sub>

Answer (score 17):

Milking a venomous snake means to remove venom from its fangs.  As discussed in this [Wired](http://www.wired.com/2014/11/how-to-make-antivenum/) article.